# ASP.Net MVC attribute-routed HTTP POST action not getting correct parameter

Tags: asp.net-mvc, attributerouting

I have following controller with attribute routing. While making AJAX request with some parameter to "FileActionDefault" action, I have get routing attribute instead of AJAX action request parameters.

```
[RoutePrefix("DocumentsManagement/FileExplorer"), Route("{action=index}")]

    public class FileExplorerController : Controller
    {
        public ActionResult Index()
        {
            return View(MVC.Views.DocumentsManagement.FileExplorer.Index);
        }
        [Route("FileActionDefault")]
        public ActionResult FileActionDefault(FileExplorerParams args)
        {
           //In "args", I have get routing attribute "FileActionDefault" instead of AJAX action request parameters 
        }
   }
```

Could you please provide some suggestion to get AJAX action parameters in  "FileActionDefault" method.

Also find AJAX request details
[image]

Comment: Please provide the javascript code where you call this method as well.

Comment: I have added AJAX request details at above

Comment: hmnn..interestng, this should work. I hope you have enabled attribute routing in your config.  Just a try, decorate the method `FileActionDefault` with `[HttpPost]` attribute / just try specifying `[FromBody]FileExplorerParams args`

Comment: Replace `Route` with `HttpPost` attribute. If it still not working maybe using camelCase for your action instead of PascalCase may help.

Comment: Missing `HttpPost` attribute on action.

Comment: I have added HttpPost attribute, but its not working. Any other suggestions? Additional info: I have used MVC not WebAPI

Comment: is attribute routing enabled?

Comment: yes, pls refer following code block                                                   public class RouteConfig
    {
        public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
        {
            routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");
            routes.IgnoreRoute("Content/{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");

            routes.MapMvcAttributeRoutes();
        }
    }